# Como separar registros de un archivo plano txt y agregarlos a listas diferentes en c#

Tags: c#, lista, txt

Tengo un archivo plano txt con dos productos Azul y Rosa, lo que necesito es que cada que encuentre un producto agrupe esos registros agregue los registros a una lista y a su vez crear un archivo txt único para cada producto.

Este es el archivo txt:

> ```
> AZUL  
> LUIS ANTONIO ROJAS NUNEZ  
> ALVARO RICARDO RAMIREZ SILV                
> CARLOS ALBERTO RUIZ FLOREZ  
> CRISTIAN EDUARDO VILLASENOR    
> JUAN MANUEL SALINAS ZAVALET  
> ROSA  
> YESICA NAYELLI CORTES ARTEA  
> LUISA VALERIA MORA LARA     
> KARINA CABRALES GUILLEN     
> ALMA DANIELA ORTIZ MENDOZA  
> IVAN YAHIR JAIME CERVANTES
> ```

Este es mi código tengo la lectura del archivo:

```
private void escribirArchivoMulti(string ruta)
    {
        string datos = String.Empty;
        string[] registros;
        List<String> listAzul = new List<string>();
        List<String> listRosa = new List<string>();
        List<String> productos = new List<string>();

        datos = File.ReadAllText(ruta, Encoding.Default);

        if (datos.Contains("\n"))
            registros = datos.Split('\n');
        else
            registros = datos.Split('\r');

        foreach (string registro in registros)
        {
            if (registro.StartsWith("AZUL"))
            {
            //    productos.Add(registro.Substring(13, 30).Trim());

            //    listRosa.Add(registro);

            //    if (registro.Substring(13, 30).Trim().Equals("INOVAG ROSA"))
            //    {
                       
            //    }
            }

            listAzul.Add(registro);
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(ruta + ".AZUL", listAzul, Encoding.UTF8);
        File.WriteAllLines(ruta + ".ROSA", listRosa, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

Comment: Primero,mejor que uses `File.ReadAllLines` y te ahorras tener que separar manualmente las lineas. Luego, el problema es que los datos son secuenciales, no tiene el producto cada persona. La forma en lo que yo lo enfocaría sería tener una bandera que cambie al leer azul o rosa, y a partir de ese momento meta lo siguiente que lea a listaazul o listarosa dependiendo del valor de esa bandera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la **función ReadAllLines** de la **clase File**, la cual te va a devolver un arreglo de tipo **string** que va a contener todas las líneas de tu txt:

```
string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(ruta);
```

Posteriormente podrías usar **Linq**:

```
var grupoAzul = lineas.TakeWhile(item => item != "Rosa").Where(l => l != "Azul").ToList();
```

La **función** **TakeWhile** nos va a tomar de tu colección original(lineas) todos los elementos mientras no encuentre el elemento **"Rosa"** y posteriormente va a aplicar un filtro **Where** para obtener después de aplicar **TakeWhile**, todos los elementos que no sean **"Azul"**, ya que si aplicas el **TakeWhile** solamente también quedaría incluido el primer elemento de la colección original(lineas) que es **"Azul"**. Si quisieras que también saliera el elemento **"Azul"** pues no aplicas el **Where** quedando así:

```
var grupoAzul = lineas.TakeWhile(item => item != "Rosa").ToList();
```

Ya tienes todos los elementos que pertenecen al grupo Azul, ahora faltaría los que pertenecen al grupo Rosa. Para esto debes usar la **función** **SkipWhile**:

```
var grupoRosa = lineas.SkipWhile(item => item != "Rosa").Where(l => l != "Rosa").ToList();
```

Esta función lo que va a hacer es lo contrario a **TakeWhile**, es decir va a descartar los elementos de la colección original hasta que no se encuentre al elemento **"Rosa"**, cuando se encuentre al elemento Rosa entonces devolverá todos los elementos que vendrían después de este. Igualmente se usa el **Where** para filtrar los elementos y quitar la palabra **"Rosa"**, si quisieras que "Rosa" saliera pues quita el **Where**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Para usar la **clase File** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Para más información sobre **TakeWhile** puedes entrar aquí:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/take

Para más información sobre **SkipWhile** puedes entrar aquí:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/skip